# SSH Tunneling not working properly

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunnel

I created an SSH tunnel via Putty and configured firefox to use it. Everything is working properly.

I have a spare AWS server that I am using for this purpose. I have verified that firefox is indeed using the proxy by checking my IP address.

Now, I want to be able to use this tunneling proxy to access Facebook which is blocked at my workplace.

When I try to access Facebook via firefox with the tunnel, it still says that facebook is blocked?

What is going on here?

Comment: As for your question about ssh tunneling, could you please include more details how you do this? I had an experience with this and succeed so I will try to answer this too.

Answer (score 1):

You can reach the same effect, i.e. to see facebook page and everything is forbidden in your network, by using [Tor Browser](https://www.torproject.org/projects/torbrowser.html.en)